# Get Inner Text of Span and wrap with new span with a class

Tags: jquery, html

I have a page with some HTML on which I need to get hold of to wrap an additional span tag around with a class on it.

```
<span class="VIEWBOX" id="_Datacomp_c_importantnote">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. vestibulum vel tellus. Morbi suscipit enim ac <BR>
</span>
```

I cannot use the class / ID that is in the parent span so i need to create a new one.

I have written

```
var innnerNoteText = $('#_Datacomp_c_importantnote').text();
innerNoteText.wrap('<span class="noteText"></span>');
```

But this isn't working, any help would be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
$('#_Datacomp_c_importantnote').wrapInner('<span class="noteText"></span>');
```

http://api.jquery.com/wrapInner/

Comment: oh word, that's better than mine.

Answer (score 0):

`$('...').text()` returns a string, there is no method `wrap`.

You have to call the `wrap()` method on the jQuery object:

```
$('#_Datacomp_c_importantnote').wrap('<span class="noteText"></span>');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EkAPu/

Answer (score 0):

`$('#_Datacomp_c_importantnote').html('<span class="noteText">' + $(this).text() + '</span>');`